# How do I hide nodes tagged with a specific taxonomy term in views?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, flags

I'm on d7. I  have a multi taxonomy term vocabulary that I allow users to add up to three terms. I'm using the flag term module and have a global flag set up to flag a term as hidden.
Ive set up a filter in my view that only shows nodes that have terms that are NOT flagged as "hidden".  This is working when one a node only has one term that is hidden, but when it has two or more that are not, it shows the node in my view. How can I make it so that if a node has a term flagged as "hidden" it doesn't show up in my view list even if it has another term that is not flagged?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new filter to your view.

- Filter criterion: Has taxonomy term
- Vocabulary: Corresponding vocabulary
- Operator: Is none of
- And select the hidden term in the dropdown

Comment: Thanks for the reply, though its not quite what I'm looking for. I can't determine what terms i will need to hide because they haven't been created yet. I let users create terms, and if my moderators or I feel a created term is inappropriate then we want to be able to hide it. I don't necessarily want my moderators messing around with my views, so I set up a flag to "hide" a term and set up a filter in views that filters out nodes tagged with a term that has been flagged "hidden".

Comment: Everything works when I only have one term on a node, but if there is more than one it does not. Any other suggestions? I feel like I need to tell views to not show nodes in my list that have ANY terms that are flagged hidden, but I'm not sure how.